# Weak dependency on shared library on Linux

Tags: c, linux, ld, dlopen

I want to make my executable to be "optionally dependent" on other shared object. Thus it will be able to run without some symbols if DSO is absent.

I can achieve this with `dlopen/dlsym` calls but I have to manually load each symbol and add wrappers for them like this:

```
void *my_lib = dlopen("my_lib.so", RTLD_LAZY);  
if (!my_lib)  {
    // ok, I promise not to touch my_lib symbols
} else {
    my_foo_ptr = dlsym(my_lib, "my_foo");
    my_bar_ptr = dlsym(my_lib, "my_bar");
}

... my_foo(...) {
    assert(my_foo_ptr);
    return (*my_foo_ptr)(...);
}

... my_bar(...) {
    assert(my_foo_ptr);
    return (*my_bar_ptr)(...);
}
```

This is a dumb code and it directly depends on "my_lib.so" ABI, that means that I have to update it each time library updates.

I'm searching for some way to make `ld.so` do this for me. So the ideal would be:

```
void *my_lib = dlopen("my_lib.so", /* bring me all my symbols */);  
if (!my_lib)  {
    // ok, I promise not to touch my_lib symbols
} else {
    // ok, I can directly call symbols from my_lib.so
    my_foo();
    my_bar();
}
```

But there are two questions with this:
1. What to do with these symbols during app linkage phase? If I link to my_lib.so explicitly, the app will be strictly dependent on it and therefore unable to start without my_lib.so. If not, `ld` will complain about undefined symbols.
2. How to force `dlopen()` to make all my_lib.so symbols available to my app?

Upd: I realized that explicit linking with shared library without marking it as `DT_NEEDED` would do the trick. But I have no clue how to make `ld` do this.

Comment: 2 is strictly impossible due to how both C and shared objects work.

Comment: Could you please explain why?

Comment: It's not impossible, its called a plugin or a module.  Gdkpixbuf and imlib2 use it for images, perl,python,tcl etc... use it for extending functions.  Abiword uses them to support additional document formats.  I think if you Google howto plugin or module, you'll find a premade solution.

Comment: It's impossible because `dlopen()` can't know which symbols you expect to be placed where; that's what `dlsym()` is for.

Answer (score 3):

It might be more sensible to write a module which understands your programs needs that minimises the interaction between your program and this library, then link that code against your library. Think of something like a music player: rather than do this kind of dance for each audio format, create a simple interface, then create a separately compiled module for each audio format and have each module link against teh appropriate support libraries. This has the advantages that you can ensure that your modules all have the same symbols and handling them is simpler: when you load the module, create a struct with function pointers, then when you call the module, just check if the struct is null and call the function pointer (this is probably sensible to do via a macro). This also means you can easily add different versions of this functionality, if that is desirable.

Comment: This is actually the same idea bit more object oriented, the same boilerplate code just moved to separate modules. Am I right?

Comment: Also I have no problems with "many" libraries, I have only one. But app have to gracefully outlive it's absence in runtime.

Comment: Yes, it's basically an object oriented system. It potentially means that you can keep the library interface small, which is much easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

While I appreciate [apmasell's object oriented approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11970893/1162141) for new code, it is not always feasible with an existing code base.  Fortunately there is a mechanism to allow the loaded module to export its own functions:

```
 -Wl,-init,<function name> and -Wl,-fini,<function name>
```

If your linker does not support this, you can write your own init function and load it with `dlsym()`.  So for each module you would have a function called something like `void init_module(void *handle);` (where `handle` is the handle from dlopen) that exports any of its own needed symbols.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible but probably more work than you're willing to invest. To do it:

1. You'll need to create a patches version of GCC and expecially the binutils which allows you to create a list of "optional" symbols (i.e. ones for which the dynamic loader won't complain when they're missing).
2. You'll have to patch the dynamic loader to understand your symbols.

A much more simple approach is probably to use a [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) which a tool (= script or simple C program) can read and use to generate the boiler plate C code for you.

The DSL would define all the symbols (and the parameters) and the tool would convert that to .h and .c files using the code templates above.

When `my_lib.so` changes (or when you need more symbols), you just edit the (small) DSL and rerun the scripts.

Comment: 1. Actually I can ask `ld` not to complain about unresolved symbols using `--unresolved-symbols=ignore-all` but it seems error prone. And I'm not sure if it will generate `@plt`'s for them 2. By default  dynamic symbol is loaded only when it referenced first time, so if it added to dynamic symbol table by `dlopen` in advance, it should be dereferenced correctly. Simple approach it is how i'm doing it now. But I feel that someone (like `ld.so`) can do it for me :)

Comment: 1. Ignoring unresolved symbols is for creating libraries. These always depend on other libraries but you don't want to link against them when building the *.so/*.a file (for obvious reasons). 2. This would be simple to do on an Amiga, for example, but on Unix, the shared libraries were built to replace the old archive files. The whole system isn't designed for "real" dynamic loading. They just moved part of the static linker into the code that loads an executable.

Comment: That means: The dynamic exe loader `ld.so` will load all symbols right away (unlike `dlopen()`). It doesn't understand/support the concept of "optional symbols". `dlopen()`, on the other hand, allows to load libraries at any time but there is no automatic support for this. You will have to write all this stupid, boring boiler plate code one way or another.

Comment: Seems like I got it: symbols loaded by `dlopen()` with `RTLD_GLOBAL` or `RTLD_DEEPBIND` affect only subsequently loaded libraries, leaving already loaded DSOs untouched since relocations for them are already done. Correct?

Comment: What is `dlopen()` supposed to do when you open/load the same shared library again? It wouldn't make sense to create a second copy - there might be internal data structures and if you call `foo()` from the second copy which needs an internal `bar()`, which one should it call? Always returning the same instance is probably the only correct solution.

Comment: You can rename library and load it twice using different names and everything will be ok. It will bring you 2 different isolated local lookup scopes unless `RTLD_GLOBRAL` or `RTLD_DEEPBIND` specified. With `RTLD_GLOBAL` weird things can happen like dereferencing symbol requested in second library with symbol declared in first. That happens because symbols in global scope can not be overridden. This is why `LD_PRELOAD` trick works.

Comment: Turns out that using `RTLD_GLOBRAL` or `RTLD_DEEPBIND` for this is unhealthy solution anyway.